# Derivative of $\mathrm{L}_2$ norm of function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, jacobian

I would like to find the derivative of the function $g$ with respect to $(\theta, z)$ where $y$ and $w$ are independent of $(\theta, z)$ and $\parallel\cdot\parallel_2$ denotes the $\mathrm{L}_2$ distance.
$$
g(\theta, z) = \parallel f(\theta, z) - y\parallel_2-w
$$
What is its gradient/jacobian?

$$
\nabla_{\theta, z} \,\,g(\theta, z) = \,\,?
$$

Comment: Maybe could write $\parallel f(\theta, z)-y\parallel_2 = \left((f(\theta, z) - y)^\top (f(\theta, z) - y)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: and then its derivative would be $(f(\theta, z) - y) \cdot J_f(\theta, z)$ where $J_f$ is the Jacobian of $f$ with respect to $(\theta, z)$

Comment: You shall go back to the definition: try to write $g(\theta+\vartheta,z+h)=g(\theta,z)+\mathrm{d}g(\theta,z)[\vartheta,h]+o_{\|(\vartheta,h)\|\to0}(\|(\vartheta,h)\|)$ where $\mathrm{d}g(\theta,z)$ is the differential of $g$ at the point $(\theta,z)$. By the way, could you tell us where does $(\theta,z)$ live?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$
Before
taking derivatives, rearrange the equation to put all the scalars on the LHS and all the vectors on the RHS.
$$\eqalign{
(g+w)^2 &= \big\|f-y\big\|^2_F \;=\; (f-y):(f-y) \\
}$$
Define the Jacobian of $f$ with respect to the vector of parameters $p$.
$$\eqalign{
p &= \pmatrix{\theta\\z}, \quad
J &= \grad{f}{p} \quad\implies\quad df = J\,dp \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and thence the Jacobian of $g$.
$$\eqalign{
2(g+w)\,dg &= 2(f-y):df \\
dg &= (g+w)^{-1}\;(f-y):(J\,dp) \\
   &= (g+w)^{-1}\;J^T\big(f-y\big):dp \\
\grad{g}{p}
 &= \frac{J^T\big(f-y\big)}{g+w} 
\;=\; \frac{J^T\big(f-y\big)}{\big\|f-y\big\|_F} \\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|_F^2\\
}$$
which is sometimes called the double-dot product.

When $(A,B)$ are vectors, this corresponds to the standard dot product.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm so confused by this

Comment: I am not using the Frobenius inner product or anything that complex

Comment: If I define $\xi = (\theta, z)$ then I am looking to compute
$$
\nabla_\xi \left[(f(\xi) - y)^\top (f(\xi)-y)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\left[(f(\xi) - y)^\top (f(\xi)-y)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot 2 (f(\xi) - y) J_f(\xi)
$$

Comment: Which I think should be
$$
\frac{(f(\xi) - y) J_f(\xi)}{\parallel f(\xi) - y\parallel_2}
$$

Comment: AAAAH but then $|| f(\xi) - y||_2 = g(\xi) - w$